# Basic lighting setup for clothing photography

Tags: studio-lighting

My wife is setting up a store to sell clothes online. Is there a basic DIY solution for lighting. I have a small light box for smaller items but I need something to photograph dresses on a manikin. Is it the same principle just on a larger scale?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this [site](http://www.tabletopstudio.com/clothing_photography.html) might help you on how to Light cloth.

Comment: Hi zlippr, welcome to the site. Could you summarize the main points to be taken into consideration? Obviously the link will give the full story but it is desiderable that answers are self contained, to prevent link rot for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest lighting solution for you would be to bounce the light (ideally a small flashgun) off a large neutral coloured wall. This will get you fairly close to the results you're getting from a light tent (but the light will be a bit more directional and you may get soft shadows behind).